# Overview different type of spheres

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been looking for info about sphere types, but could really use a quick summary about these type of spheres:

Quadsphere /
Isosphere /
Uvsphere

I'm interested in their best-use cases, but so far I've found conflicting info..some say for example the uv sphere is either great/terrible for modeling organic matter.
Also, is the uvsphere related to uv mapping?
Hope someone can give a clear overview!

Comment: They are just different "subdivision" methods used to create faces on a sphere. _UV Sphere_ uses quads around the "equator" but the poles are comprised of tri's. An Icosphere is comprised of tri's by default, but can include other shapes depending on the parameters you define in the _operator panel_ (the little options tab that  appears in the bottom left after you do an action). Lastly, a Quad Sphere is comprised entirely of quads (albeit a bit misshapen and perhaps not uniform size). Each has its advantages/disadvantages depending on your use case.

Comment: Also, there is no "right" way to UV map a sphere - only best approximations for a use case - hence why there are hundreds of different projection methods for the planet earth, each attempting to create an "accurate" 2D map with no deformation or scaling issues, but also each suffering from some sort of inaccuracy.

Comment: "Each has its advantages/disadvantages depending on your use case." Right, but can you name examples of when you would use one over the other? Is there a scenario where you absolutely would always use the quadsphere?

Comment: UV sphere is best for most image textures. There will be visible "pinching" at the poles, but this can be rather easily negated by keeping the affected areas out of view, and/or rotating the texture mapping as needed. If, on the other hand, you wanted to animate a ball that bounces and deforms heavily (squashes) as it does, a UV sphere would be no good because the tri's (especially when deformed) could introduce significant shading errors, so a quad sphere is best. Icosphere's are good for things that are going to be exported to a game engine, because most game engines shade based on tri's.

Comment: Thanks, thats the sort of practical usecases I was looking for!